# Getting 3 divs to equally fill parent

Tags: html, css

I have an aside (sidebar) and I'm trying to break it up into 3 sections equally.
Here's what it looks like:

[image]

This is my html:

```
        <aside id="sidebar">
            <div id="side_events">
                Events
            </div>
            <div id="side_trailer">
                Trailer
            </div>
            <div id="side_advertisement">
                Advertisement
            </div>                    
        </aside>
```

This is the majority of my CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
    display: block;
}
body{
    width: 100%; /*always specify this when using flexBox*/ 
    height:100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center; /*way of centering the website*/
    background-image:url('bg2.jpg');
}
#wrapper{
    max-width: 850px;
    display: -webkit-box; /*means this is a box with children inside*/
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; /*allows site to grow or shrink 1 = flex 0 = statix*/
    background-color: #B137D6;
}
#body_div{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    color:#000000;
}
#main_section{
    border:1px solid blue;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; 
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
}
#sidebar{
    width: 210px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #999999;
    border:#FF0000 1px solid;
}
#side_events,
#side_trailer,
#side_advertisement{
    height:33.333%;
}
#side_events{
    background:#102A50;
    display:block;
}
#side_trailer{
    background:#173B72;
    display:block;
}
#side_advertisement{
    background:#296CD0;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://tinkerbin.com/6SHqiynR

Comment: I was thinking that that was what you were thinking for.  Glad you got it solved, bravo JOPLOmacedo

Comment: Actually is doesn't work as well within my wrapper. I've added my entire CSS. I think something might be throwing it off. What I get is an aside of height 60 and children height 20 each. So they're all equal but now my aside is too small

Comment: @Batman: You forgot to add 100% height to the `html` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/ecFnt/6/

Comment: Hmm I see. I was hoping I didn't have to do that. When I do it it adds space between the wrapper and the footer: http://jumpshare.com/v/7Ieiad?b=27uHjy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `#sidebar` childs height to 100%/3 = 33.333%, but to achieve this you need also to set `html` and `body` tags height to 100%:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#side_events,
#side_trailer,
#side_advertisement{
    height:33.333%;
}
```

Most of the time you have to apply a 100% height to the parent DIV to get this working.

Comment: I think that's what I've done but now I have a really small aside.
http://jumpshare.com/v/bIJ06n?b=G7JDn3

Comment: @Batman: you missed `html{height:100%;}`, working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ecFnt/6/

Answer (score 0):

Your height of your parent element is auto and the child elements are 100%.  So you need to define the parent element height in order for the child elements to be defined as 100%.

You parent element (#sidebar) has 100% height.

I wrote a jsfiddle so you could see my point of the 100% height on the parent element.  The parent element is set to 100% but has nothing to derive 100% from.  So I set the container in the example to a define height.   http://jsfiddle.net/rtLeM/

```
                  <!-- HTML -->
                 <div id="container">  
                   <aside id="sidebar">
                     <div id="side_events">
                       Events
                     </div>
                     <div id="side_trailer">
                       Trailer
                     </div>
                     <div id="side_advertisement">
                       Advertisement
                     </div>                    
                   </aside>
                 </div>

                 /* CSS */
                 #container{
                    height:300px;
                 }
                 #sidebar{
                    width:150px;
                    height:100%;

                 }
                 #side_events{
                    height:33%;
                    width:100%;
                    display:block;
                    background-color:#555;
                 }

                 #side_trailer{
                    height:33%;
                    width:100%;
                    display:block;
                    background-color:#999;
                 }

                 #side_advertisement{
                    height:33%;
                    width:100%;
                    display:block;
                    background-color:#333;
                 }
```

Comment: I "inspected elements" and found the height to the sidebar to be 685px. So I set it as that and it seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a child element set to 100% and the parent is set 100px, the child element will be 100px because it is 100% of the parent element.  If the parent element is auto then the child element does not know what to be 100% of.

Comment: I've changed the height to the parent to 100% and children to 33% but now I get this: http://jumpshare.com/v/bIJ06n?b=G7JDn3